# Why is YUI Menu waiting for my page images to load?

Tags: yui, yui-menu

**Edit:** This is a confirmed bug in jQuery 1.3.1. It is fixed in jQuery 1.3.2.

---

I have a YUI menu control exactly like [this sample](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/menu/topnavfrommarkup_source.html) with sub menus along the top.

I tried using Yahoo's code to initialize the menu :

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onContentReady("mnuTopNav", function() {

    var oMenuBar = new YAHOO.widget.MenuBar("mnuTopNav", {
        autosubmenudisplay: true,
        hidedelay: 750,
        lazyload: true
    });

    oMenuBar.render();
});
```

I am seeing issues with pages that have images that take time to load.

I noticed that the headings would instantly appear (Communication/Shopping/Entertainment), but that the little arrows indicating there are sub-items wouldn't appear until all images are loaded.

I thought this very strange. I even tried switching out the code to JQuery to see if would initialize before the images are done loading (thats what `$(function()` i thought was supposed to do).

```
$(function(){


        var oMenuBar = new YAHOO.widget.MenuBar("mnuTopNav", {
            autosubmenudisplay: true,
            hidedelay: 750,
            lazyload: true
        });

        oMenuBar.render();
});
```

To my amazement I still had the same issue. The menu would not initialize until the whole page was loaded.

It is definitely the images that are being waited for.

Note: this problem is only in internet explorer. Firefox seems to raise this onContentReady event BEFORE the images are loaded.

Can i work around this problem?

---

**Edit:** This is a confirmed bug in jQuery 1.3.1. It is fixed in jQuery 1.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo's onContentReady(...) seems to wait for images to load for some reason so I've stopped using that.

In addition there appears to be a JQuery bug in how $(function() {  }); works

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477463) by me trying to get more specifics on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using YUI's onAvailable() instead of onContentReady()?  From [YUI's docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/#onavailable):

> The onContentReady method shares an
>   identical syntax with onAvailable. The
>   material difference between the two
>   methods is that onContentReady waits
>   until both the target element and its
>   nextSibling in the DOM respond to
>   getElementById. This guarantees that
>   the target element's contents will
>   have loaded fully (excepting any
>   dynamic content you might add later
>   via script). If onContentReady never
>   detects a nextSibling, it fires with
>   the window.load event.

My guess is that the browser needs to load images onto the DOM before the nextSibling attribute works, so onContentReady() is waiting for that.

Comment: thanks daniel. i'll check it out. i integrated first and read docs later. in fact last night i watched a video from yahoo's site about the menu. they have some good stuff. i don't think they mentioned either of those methods though. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/

Answer (score 0):

for jQuery you should do this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){


        var oMenuBar = new YAHOO.widget.MenuBar("mnuTopNav", {
            autosubmenudisplay: true,
            hidedelay: 750,
            lazyload: true
        });

        oMenuBar.render();
   });
```

Comment: this is actually exactly equivalent to what I have above. it turns out I was using JQuery 1.3.1 which waits for all images to load (see below)