# JQuery is waiting for images to load before executing document.ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.3

**Update:**
This bug has been confirmed by at least two others. Even if you dont read my full post - if you're reading this and using JQuery 1.3.1 then **stop using it** if you're relying on any handlers that you want to execute when the DOM is complete but before the page's images have loaded.

**Update2**: Thanks to [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20/tom) (user id 20!)  for posting the [link to the ticket](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/3988#preview) on the jQuery bug tracker.

**Update3 - 2009/01/28:** The issue has been properly resolved (for those for whom reverting to 1.2.6 is not an option). For anyone currently using 1.3.1 and needing an immediate fix you can read the accepted answer below for direction. Thanks John.

---

I just upgraded to JQuery 1.3.1, and it took me several hours to realize that my beloved

```
$(function( ) {  ... }
```

syntax was now waiting for the entire page to load (including images) before executing the function body. I was seeing [strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477348/) when trying to integrate Yahoo's menus. (Fortunately I had some slow loading images on my page which made me aware of the problem)!

I made a test file becasue I figured something more complex was going on, but I still had the same symptoms even with this simple file.

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
   <script>
    $(function() {    
      alert("Ready"); 
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>      
  <img src="<PATH_TO_DYNAMIC_IMAGE>_1.jpg" />
  <img src="<PATH_TO_DYNAMIC_IMAGE>_2.jpg" />
  <img src="<PATH_TO_DYNAMIC_IMAGE>_3.jpg" />
  <img src="<PATH_TO_DYNAMIC_IMAGE>_4.jpg" />       
</body>
```

Different versions of JQuery had different results:

- What happens in version 1.2.6 is that alert box is shown instantly and then I see the images loading behind it (expected and documented behavior).
- What happens in version 1.3.1 is that the images all load and only then will the alert box be shown.

Whats going on! Is this a new feature (I cant imagine why) or a bug?

**Important: This only seems to be an issue in IE and not firefox**

*Sorry I dont have a dynamic image file that is publically accessible to make it easier for others to see this. If you want to test it out I suggest using a large image file picked randomly from google images and clear your cache.*

Comment: I'm experiencing the EXACT same problem with the most recent version of jQuery. Please keep this question updated based on any feedback that you get.

Comment: @tom definitely will. i emailed and twittered john resig who initially wrote JQuery. i personally am in no hurry for a bugfix (i'm back to 1.2.6) but they really need to take that version down as the released version on jquery.com!

Comment: @Simon - I submitted a ticket this afternoon about this problem. Ah, the joys of free software ;) They'll get it fixed soon enough, I'm sure - good devs on the team - but it sucks for me because I can't revert back to 1.2.6 =T

Comment: @tom do you (or anyone else) have a URL that I can view the status?

Comment: Yeah, link to the ticket would be appreciated.  Their bug tracker breaks on me when I go to the custom query page /sigh.  Seeing a list of open bugs/tickets against a release should be something there's a link for on the front page.

Comment: @cletus someone added the link below, but i'll add it up top now

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This was due to jQuery bugs #[2614](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/2614) and #[3880](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/3880) - there were definite problems with the ready code in IE in 1.2.6 and in 1.3 - and now a different set of problems in 1.3.1.

A larger discussion can be found here:
http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/3abf45d3fd4d50fc

And the ticket related to the issue can be found here (if you find additional issues with the fix, please re-open the ticket and post to the above jquery-dev thread):
http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/3988

I just landed a fix for this in SVN rev [6170](http://dev.jquery.com/changeset/6170).

I just pushed up a new nightly that you can use until 1.3.2 final comes out: 
http://code.jquery.com/nightlies/jquery-2009-01-28.js

Sorry in the delay for getting a fix out - was traveling this week.

Comment: awesome -- Resig to the rescue :)

Comment: @jresig - any reason why 1.3.1 is still the 'current release' on jQuery.com? i'd hate to see too many people downloading it without knowing about this bug. hopefully anyone using jquery is hungry enough for the newest version that they are upgrading regularly

Comment: @Simon: We can't just push out releases whenever we feel like it - we have to coordinate with a number of people. We're working on getting something out, quite soon, but it might be a little bit.

Answer (score 4):

There are some things that just can't be unit tested. Just confirmed in IE6+7 and 1.3.1. Holy hell, what a huge regression.

So, do you have time to report this? Just checked and it's not a known bug for 1.3.1.

Comment: if you already know where to check and you could report it that would be great. its 4:50am for me and im about to go to bed! the funny thing is i'm coding a brand new site and the ONLY thing I was using JQuery for so far was this fundamental task!

Comment: oh and thanks for humoring me and believing the unbelievable :)

Answer (score 4):

[Here's an update of the ticket I submitted](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/3988#preview). It seems as if [@Webdawson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477463/jquery-is-waiting-for-images-to-load-before-executing-document-ready#480721) has attached a sample page to the ticket.

Comment: @tom - great! thats my bug! i love the gigantic 3MB image they used! awesome. thanks for letting me outsource my bug reporting through you. my days of doing that are over - once you start you cant stop. i got dissilusioned when MS always closed my bugs or said wont fix (except for SQL server bugs!)

Answer (score 3):

yes i've added an example, its clearly a bug in IE6 & 7 (i havn't tested it in other IE versions). It seems as if the 1.3.1 Version has a lot of bugs. :(

Here is the example link: http://www.kollermedia.at/jquery_bug.html

Comment: i'd have thought this was the kind of showstopper that meant they'd take down 1.3.1 from their site (at least as being the current release). going to hang a lot of sites for people or make them very unresponsive. oh well.