# Beyond stumped; Odd JQuery Cycle behavior in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer

I'm using the [JQuery Cycle Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) in an attempt to fade in/out images for a slide show.  I am able to get it working in Firefox and Safari, however, when I view in Internet Explorer, I see very unexpected behavior.

In Internet Explorer, the cycling is happening as expected, but some of the images do not display.  They simply display a red X.  The example site can be viewed here:

http://913solutions.com/richmond-va/siding

The first image doesn't show in IE, but does in Firefox and Safari.  It's almost like IE doesn't find the image on the server at all.  Here's the image directly:

http://913solutions.com/images/siding/siding1-350px.jpg

I'm completely lost here.  Can anyone verify my situation?  Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome either.

Comment: IE7 finds the image after all are loaded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477463/jquery-is-waiting-for-images-to-load-before-executing-document-ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It didnt show in chrome which leads me to think it's a corrupted jpg, i opened it up in notepad++ and noticed a bunch of xml/non-binary data, it could just be a comment or something but i dont know, maybe that info will help with the problem.

the start of the xml looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.print.PageFormat.PMHorizontalRes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.print.ticket.creator</key>
        <string>com.apple.jobticket</string>
```

it looks like there is a little more information on it here:

http://osdir.com/ml/video.image-magick.user/2002-09/msg00477.html

Comment: It looks like you are correct!  I went and snagged the original, adjusted the dimensions, saved it, and poof, it worked.  Amazing how long I've been banging my head against the wall over that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your images are at 72 pixels/inch.

Often if you create jpgs from print work they are at 300 pixels/inch, and even if their dimensions are correct... they may not display properly in all browsers.