# jQuery event for images loaded

Tags: jquery, dom

Is it possible to detect when all images are loaded via a jQuery event?

Ideally, there should be a

```
$(document).idle(function()
{
}
```

or

```
$(document).contentLoaded(function()
{
}
```

But I can't find such a thing.

I thought of attaching an event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var imageTotal = $('img').length;
    var imageCount = 0;        
    $('img').load(function(){if(++imageCount == imageTotal) doStuff();});
}
```

But will this break if an image fails to load? It's critically important for the method to be called, and at the right time.

Comment: Why don't you use the onload event: $(window).load(doStuff)? Onload will, however, wait for other resources too (e.g. scripts, stylesheets & flash) and not just images, which may or may not be OK to you.

Comment: Attaching a load event to all your img tags, as you have in your code sample, should be functional. If an image fails to load doStuff() won't be called, but that seems reasonable given your requirement that all the images must be loaded.

Comment: The .load() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached

Answer (score 117):

Per jQuery's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), there are a number of caveats for using the load event with images. As noted in another answer, the ahpi.imgload.js plugin is broken, but the linked Paul Irish gist is no longer maintained.

Per Paul Irish, the **canonical plugin for detecting image load complete events** is now at:

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: This is the answer- handles multiple images, cached images, browser quirks, broken images, and it's current. Beautiful.

Comment: tested it today. was up and running in 2 minutes.

Comment: Agree with @Yarin, good documentation, easy to use, multiple, cached, broken, and current. Love it.

Comment: On the downside, however, [imagesLoaded does not support IE7](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/74) if that's important to you.

Comment: A quick and simple 2-line fix to get [imagesLoaded working on IE7](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/76).

Answer (score 64):

If you want to check for not all images, but a specific one (eg. an image that you replaced dynamically after DOM is already complete) you can use this:

```
$('#myImage').attr('src', 'image.jpg').on("load", function() {  
  alert('Image Loaded');  
});
```

Comment: Be careful, because `load()` will not trigger when an image is already loaded. This can happens easily when an image is in the user's browser cache. You can check if an image is already loaded using `$('#myImage').prop('complete')`, which returns true when an image is loaded.

Comment: Why does this have so many votes when it a) doesn't answer his question and b) gives a poor solution besides? (Meanshile the correct answer is @johnpolacek's and has 1 vote)

Comment: WARNING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   This is not the correct answer.  johnpolacek has the correct answer.  Please vote his answer up.

Comment: These objections don't appear to be relevant anymore except in a very specific circumstance: Webkit when you change the src of an image to the exact same src as before. For images you just added to the DOM, $(...).load() should be enough. Tested in current FF and Chrome, and IE6-9: http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/tXVCe/2/

Comment: +1 Works fine when (you know that) the image is not in the browsers cache.

Comment: This answer is fine for some applications, and plugin-free. For example, if you just need to do some positioning in JS when an image-load changes the size of an element, then images that have already loaded don't matter.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini One more exception to add to that list: If the image is cached, the load event will happen before it gets bound to using this code. The fix is to simply swap the order of `.attr` and `.load`.

Answer (score 28):

You can use my plugin [*waitForImages*](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) to handle this...

```
$(document).waitForImages(function() {
   // Loaded.
});
```

The advantage of this is you can localise it to one ancestor element and it can [optionally](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages#advanced) detect images referenced in the CSS.

This is just the tip of the iceberg though, check the [documentation](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages/blob/master/README.md) for more functionality.

Comment: Hi Alex, looks promising. But like the mentioned in the answers and comments given by johnpolacek and hirisov, does it cover the case when the image is already in the browser cache?

Comment: I have a process that creates an image and loads it dynamically after the page has already been loaded, and I needed to show an ajax loader while the user waits.  This plugin works perfectly for that use case.  You have to call the function after setting the img src property however!

Answer (score 20):

Use of the jQuery $().load() as an IMG event handler isn't guaranteed.  If the image loads from the cache, some browsers may not fire off the event.  In the case of (older?) versions of Safari, if you changed the SRC property of an IMG element *to the same value*, the onload event will NOT fire.

It appears that this is recognized in the latest jQuery (1.4.x) - http://api.jquery.com/load-event - to quote:

> It is possible that the load event will not be triggered if the image is loaded from the browser cache. To account for this possibility, we can use a special load event that fires immediately if the image is ready. event.special.load is currently available as a plugin.

There is a plug-in now to recognize this case and IE's "complete" property for IMG element load states:
http://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js

Answer (score 16):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545005/3715), you can use the [jQuery load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) on the `window` object instead of the `document`:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    console.log("page finished loading now.");
});
```

This will be triggered after all content on the page has been loaded. This differs from `jQuery(document).load(...)` which is triggered after the DOM has finished loading.

Answer (score 4):

[imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)
 Plugin is way to go ,if you need a crossbrowser solution

```
 $("<img>", {src: 'image.jpg'}).imagesLoaded( function( $images, $proper, $broken ){
 if($broken.length > 0){
 //Error CallBack
 console.log('Error');
 }
 else{
 // Load CallBack
 console.log('Load');
 }
 });
```

If You Just Need a IE WorkAround,This Will Do

```
 var img = $("<img>", {
    error: function() {console.log('error'); },
    load: function() {console.log('load');}
    });
  img.attr('src','image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a note on the ahpi.imgload.js plugin at the moment saying that it is currently broken, and to try this gist instead:
https://gist.github.com/797120/7176db676f1e0e20d7c23933f9fc655c2f120c58

Answer (score 2):

#### For same-origin images, you could use:

```
$.get('http://www.your_domain.com/image.jpg', imgLoaded);

function imgLoaded(){
    console.log(this, 'loaded');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this plugin may be useful: http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

```
  function CheckImageLoadingState()
  {
     var counter = 0;
     var length = 0;

     jQuery('#siteContent img').each(function() 
     {
        if(jQuery(this).attr('src').match(/(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/))
          length++;
     });

     jQuery('#siteContent img').each(function() 
     {  
        if(jQuery(this).attr('src').match(/(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/))
        {
           jQuery(this).load(function() 
           {
           }).each(function() {
              if(this.complete) jQuery(this).load();
            });
        }
        jQuery(this).load(function()
        {
           counter++;
           if(counter === length) 
           {  
              //function to call when all the images have been loaded
              DisplaySiteContent();
           }
        });
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "img.photo" ).load(function() {

    $(".parrentDiv").css('height',$("img.photo").height());
    // very simple

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my own script, because I found many plugins to be quite bloated, and I just wanted it to work the way I wanted. Mine checks to see if each image has a height (native image height). I've combined that with the $(window).load() function to get around the issues of caching.

I've code commented it quite heavily, so it should be interesting to look at, even if you don't use it. It works perfectly for me.

Without further ado, here it is:

[imgLoad.js script](https://github.com/JohnnyBash/imgLoad)

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for all images to load...
I found the anwser to my problem with jfriend00 here [jquery: how to listen to the image loaded event of one container div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570018/jquery-how-to-listen-to-the-image-loaded-event-of-one-container-div) .. and "if (this.complete)"
Waiting for the all thing to load and some possibly in cache !.. and i have added the "error" event...
***it's robust across all browsers***

```
$(function() { // Wait dom ready
    var $img = $('img'), // images collection
        totalImg = $img.length,
        waitImgDone = function() {
            totalImg--;
            if (!totalImg) {
                console.log($img.length+" image(s) chargée(s) !");
            }
        };
    $img.each(function() {
        if (this.complete) waitImgDone(); // already here..
        else $(this).load(waitImgDone).error(waitImgDone); // completed...
    });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/molokoloco/NWjDb/

Answer (score 0):

`window.load = function(){}`

Its fully supported by all browsers, and it will fire an event when all images are fully loaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: surely   window.onload  = function(){}