# Check image load by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" alt="thumbnail" />
```

I'm changing the `src` attribute of this image dynamically.

How do I check whether the image was loaded or not? And do something when it is loaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can handle the load event with...

```
 $('#id').load(function(){
      //handler code here
 });
```

If you only want to handle when it is changed...

```
   $('#id').attr('src','yourimage.png').load(function(){
      //handler code here
 });
```

Comment: that won't work for cached images, see my link above for solution

Answer (score 4):

Check out this answer

[jQuery event for images loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/jquery-event-for-images-loaded)

Answer (score 2):

Start here:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/simple-image-load-detection-with-load

The above assumes you are loading the image from JQuery and that is where you need to attach your additional code.

Answer (score 0):

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/6knva/

```
var link = 'http://i.treehugger.com/images/2007/5/24/120_mph_electric_car.jpg';
$('img').attr('src',link).load(function(){
      alert('image loaded');
 });
```