# jquery image gallery fadeIn

Tags: jquery, fadein

Got an annoying problem and cannot seem to rectify...

The following will fade and image out, the callback will then remove the image and insert a new one, on load of the new image it should fade back in... but it seems to be fading back in super fast or rather just showing the new image..

```
    if($('#gallery-image img').css('opacity') == 1){
        $('#gallery-image').children('img').fadeOut(sawdays.gallery.transitionTime , function(){
            $(this).remove();
            $('#gallery-image').append(newImg);
            $('#gallery-image img').load(function(){
                $(this).fadeIn(sawdays.gallery.transitionTime);
            });
        });
    }
```

I was wondering if anyone could see anything i was doing wrong with it... i've already spent too much time on this :S

Comment: var newImg = $('<img />').attr({ 'src':src , 'height':height , 'width':width , 'style':style });

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 if ( $('#gallery-image img').css('opacity') == 1 ) {
        $('#gallery-image').find('img').fadeOut(sawdays.gallery.transitionTime , function(){
           $(this).replaceWith(newImg);
           $('#gallery-image img').fadeIn(sawdays.gallery.transitionTime);
        });
  }
```

Comment: Ah, nice function i did not know about... replaceWith... thanks. However the fadeIn is still not listening to the fadeIn parameter. I have even piped it to a load function (hopefully meaning it will fadeIn when the image has loaded but no joy)... see the edit above

Comment: I was using the load so the fade in would only happen once the image had loaded properly... is this not needed?

Comment: @John I hope this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/jquery-event-for-images-loaded