# Add a Game Loader for HTML5 game

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a simple game with HTML5 and JavaScript.

Initially when the Game starts it takes some time to load images and sound.
During this time the user has to wait and the screen looks unpleasant.

So here's what i want to do

1. Check loading status of images and sound.
2. Increase % of loading as and when resources are loaded and respectively increase progress bar.

I really don't have any key from where to start. Please Guide me through.

Comment: Using the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/jquery-event-for-images-loaded) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded)  you can detect when you images are loaded and then increase the progress with each image in your desired fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Monitoring load status for all loading items can be daunting, but, in a nutshell, the best way to go about it is to do the following:

- First, add to a `totalResources` counter, so the game knows how many resources to expect.
- Add `eventListeners` to the loading resources, and add to a `loadingResources` counter. If it loads successfully or fails, add to the `loadingResources` counter.
- Once the counters are equal, either all the resources loaded, or there were some errors in loading certain files.

The catch with this method is, on rare occasions, the `loadingResources` can match the `totalResources` variable prematurely. You can fix this by making a flag that checks to see if all the resources that needed to load have started loading already.

Now, depending on how you make your game, a failed resource load shouldn't really stop the game from working. For example, if a sound doesn't load properly, it just won't play. You might want to retry or abort if a resource needs to load.

As for a % based loading, that's a bit iffy. The HTML5 spec includes a progress bar, but for multiple resources, your best bet might just be a bar that fills up as resources are loaded.

**Addendum:**

Sound files are a huge pain to load, and I've had little success perfecting it across all browsers. Here's how I went about it:

1. First, don't rely on the `load()` function to invoke loading an `audio` element. Instead, force it to play, like so:

   `sound.channels[i].volume = 0;`

   `sound.channels[i].play();`

   (Also, to replay a sound, set the `duration` to a near 0 value when the sound is paused.)
2. As to allow multiple sounds to play at the same time, it is good practice to have multiple audio elements (thus the `channels` array above). However, you don't need to wait for all the sound channels to load. Once one loads, clone the node and force a silent play again to avoid any delays.
3. It's anecdotally more reliable to use the `canplaythrough` event callback to see if a sound is ready. If a sound fails to load, use the `error` callback. The problem is that there are a number of errors that can cause a sound file to fail to load.
4. Don't forget to use `<source>` elements to allow for multiple audio formats.

Comment: a really instructive answer Jeffrey... Thanx...
Can you let me know how do i check the loading of sound file...

Comment: I added some tips. It's really a lot more complicated than I care to post (or should post) on SO, but I can email you my current loading scheme in my GameAPI if you would like some more in depth techniques. Just shoot me an email (in profile).

Comment: this definitely is quite complex... i'll hit u a mail soon

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper I just finished a resource loading script creatively named "ResourceLoader." If you're still working with your game loading code, you may want to check it out: https://github.com/jsweeneydev/ResourceLoader

Comment: looks great to me... !! will check this soon... I have a small doubt.. Will this be able to preload a sound file in an apple device becoz it does allow preloading of sound files...
Thanx in advance...

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper Well, I'm on a mac, and sounds seem to preload fine. However, I'm not entirely sure how well iOS devices support the `audio` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var assetsToLoad = [],
    assetsLoaded = 0;

var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener("load", loadHandler, false);
image.src = "image.png";
assetsToLoad.push(image);

//...Load other assests, following the same format...

function loadHandler() {
    assetsLoaded++;
    //Display "Loading" in the console while assets are being loaded
    console.log("Loading...");
    //If everthing is loaded, do this:
    if (assetsLoaded === assetsToLoad.length) {
      //Make the game play, possibly by changing its state from "loading" to "playing"
      console.log("All assets loaded");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought of adding my two cents worth. In addition to having a `loadCounter`, I suggest you have an `errorCounter` and increment each of these variables depending on whether the current file was a success or a failure. At the end of your loop, you can check if the sum of these two is equal to the `totalCounter`.