# Consistent way of finding element height after nested image has loaded

Tags: jquery, image, ready

I have a `div.body`which contains an `img` amongst a couple more elements.

I need to get the height of `div.body` after `img` has been loaded.

I'm currently using the following to measure:

```
var $body = $("div.body");
$body.find("img").ready(function(){
   var bodyHeight = $body.outerHeight();
});
```

This returns the correct height 90% of the time, however some times it is returning the height not including the height of the image.

---

For example, if the other elements in `div.body` sum up to `50px`, and my image has a height of `150px`, I need to get `200px`, however sometimes this is returning just `50px`.

---

Why is this? Shouldn't the `.ready()` function only be called after the image has loaded?

Should I be using a different method?

What is a 100% consistent way of running this code once the image is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.ready()` runs when the entire page's DOM is loaded. You want `.load()`.

See the discussion section [here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) for an implementation that works for dynamically added content.

Comment: My understanding is that `load` will only run if the image isn't already cached?

Comment: My experience has been that it will execute when all content in the container you hook it onto is ready. It works fine on my website.

Comment: And that would be because my usage on `.load()` is only required once - The image isn't 'live' in the cache yet, as it needs to be fetched from disk. If you only need the `.load()` event while the page is loading, then this should work just fine. If you're using it on dynamically added content, then no, it won't work.

Comment: I've just changed `ready` to `load`, and the first time I loaded the page it worked fine. The second time, it didn't run the event (as the image is stored in cache).

Comment: Do the same calculation in `$(window).load()` - This is run even when the images are cached, but be aware that it won't run until _everything_ is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Per jQuery's documentation, there are a number of caveats for using the load event with images.

Take a look here:

[jQuery event for images loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/jquery-event-for-images-loaded)

and here:

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded