# Image source change event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a slide show. I want to change my slideshow's wrapper class height and width according to the the current images height and width for that I need to get image<> src load using jquery, I tried following to get image src change event but it is not working,

```
$('.classname img').load(function(){
});
```

Comment: My concern is about how to get image src change event I got height and width of image.

Answer (score 1):

Try using attr() method, to specify attribute for src property.

Setter

```
$('.classname img').attr('src','YourImageLocation');
```

getter

```
var imgUrl=$('.classname img').attr('src');
```

Comment: actually ravi, I tried that also but then it is not calling my $(document) method so I removed it and left it with above only.I only want to get src change event.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get image height and weight using width() and height(). Anyway, see this - http://jsfiddle.net/xdcj5/ i hope this will help you.

if you need get src attribute of image then you can try like this -

```
var imgLink = $('img').attr('src');
```

If even not working then try using live function http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: thanks HAD, but I want to get Image src change event, I have images height and width

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.classname img').attr('src', 'image.jpg').load(function() {  
  console.log("image loaded");
});
```

here is a SO question that might help [jQuery event for images loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/jquery-event-for-images-loaded)