# Bind data in groups

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm learning Knockout and trying something as below. Data gets displayed, but what I want is data to be bound in chunks. For example the first 3 will get bound, then the next 3,  then next 3, etc.

In other words: How can I push "people" in the observable array in "chunks".

Below is some sample code. In my actual case I'm binding *images*, and they are taking time to load, so that is why I want to bind data in chunks.

Here is my viewModel:

```
var viewModel = {
   topicsList : ko.observableArray()
};
```

Here is the data binding:

```
dispatcher(viewEvent, function(event, data){    
  $.each(data, function(){
    viewModel.people.push(this);
  });
});


ko.applyBindings(new viewModel);
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: people">
  <div data-bind="text:firstName"></div
</div>
```

For pushing people in observable array I tried something like this:

```
dispatcher(viewEvent, function(event, data) {
  var loop = 0;

  $.each(data, function(){
    ++loop;
    viewModel.topicsList.push(this);
    if(loop%3==0) {                     
      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
});
```

Comment: IMO, binding in chunks is not a correct way to tackle this problem. You may rather push people in the observable array in 'chunks'. You may push the first three first and on some event next three and so on..

Comment: You may use paging technique here.

Comment: @ShuhelAhmed: just see http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QSRBR/ example of paging.Can i divide "initialData" into chunks and and push to observable array.

Comment: The example used an external library to do the paging or generating the grid, 'knockout.simpleGrid.js'. Well, all you need to do is _load_ your initialData in 'chunks'. If you retrieve json from server, just load 3 at a time. If you have all your data available on client side, keep them in some array, just take 3 from the source and push to the array. By the way, there is no notion of 'people' in your viewModel. You have topicList there. You may consider correcting your code example.

Comment: @ShuhelAhmed: updated my post with what i am trying to make chunk of three but it is not giving me correct output. It show is only last one.

Comment: You [should](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) tell us *why* you want to divide people in chunks. If a chunk is semantic, you probably need a ViewModel to represent that. If a chunk is for display purposes, there are probably other ways to solve your problem (CSS, paging, etc.).

Comment: @Jeroen: as already stated in post in actual i am loading images, it will load first 3 and than next 3, so every chunk will get extra time to load. (I think it will clear you question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your view models a bit so that the `src` for images would be [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html): a placeholder image as a basis, or the actual image URL when it is time for the image to be loaded. Like this:

```
function personViewModel(url) {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable("Johndoe");
    self.imageUrl = ko.observable(url);
    self.mayLoad = ko.observable(false);

    self.imageSrc = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.mayLoad() ? self.imageUrl() : "http://soulclimbing.mobi/Content/Media/image-loading-animation.gif";
    });
}
```

Something like this view could be used:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: people">
  <div>
      <span data-bind="text:firstName"></span>
      <br />
      <img data-bind="attr: {src: imageSrc}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

For loading images in chunks of three, there are various options. A baseline, hackish, naive solution, with just starting a new chunk every X seconds using setInterval. Something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/VDMu2/3/).

Better would be to use the [event binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) to start download of a next image, when one is loaded. However, checking if images are loaded is very hard (caching and whatnot), so you may want to use a library to handle things. See, for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9589845/419956).