# check image has been loaded using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem- At run time I am changing/replacing src attribute of some images using jquery. These images are by default hidden. I want to display these images when these images are download and ready to display because it is also possible that some images can not be downloaded.

```
         <img id="pic_1" width="153" height="160" border="0" 
                onmouseout="this.style.border='2px solid #FFFFFF';"
                   onmouseover="this.style.border='2px solid #4585E7';" 
                                       style="visibility: hidden;" 
                                        src="**to be replaced at run time**"">
```

Please let me know any solution how can i achieve this.

Comment: You can get more ideas about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use the [`Load` event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) for this.

Something like:

```
$('#myImage').load(function() {
  //called when image is loaded
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zE6Ys/)

[Here is an example with delayed loading](http://jsfiddle.net/zE6Ys/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#imgId').load(function(){
alert('Image Loaded')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to musefan's answer, if you need it to work with cached images as well, you'll need something more than `load()`

Check https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded. It's a jQuery plugin that triggers a callback when images have been loaded. It works for cached images as well.

Check [jQuery event for images loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/910727/384155) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This code would hook to every picture you got on your site with the class "preload".

```
$(function(){
    //Hide all pictures first (You could here work on some loading animations if you want)
    $("img.preload").css("display", "none");

    //When the image is loaded, show it again
    $("img.preload").load(function(){
        $(this).css("display", "block");
    });
});
```