# How to do a process after completion of another one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to add an image by Javascript, then calculating the html element width as

```
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var el = document.getElementById('xx');
    el.innerHTML = '<img src="img.jpg" />';
    var width = el.offsetWidth;
    .....
   }, false);
}
```

but since `JavaScript` conduct all processes simultaneously, I will get the width of the element before loading the image. How can I make sure that the image has been loaded into the content; then calculating the element width?

**UPDATE:** Thanks for the answers, but I think there is a misunderstanding. `img src="img.jpg" />` does not exist in the DOM document. It will be added later by `Javascript`. Then, when trying to catch the element by `Id`, it is not there probably.

Comment: you should listen for the load event on the img.

Comment: Image preloader! Look it up.

Comment: Not exactly the load event, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/jquery-event-for-images-loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onload=function(){
     document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var el = document.getElementById('xx');
        var img = new Image();//dynamically create image
        img.src = "img.jpg";//set the src
        img.alt = "alt";
        el.appendChild(img);//append the image to the el
        img.onload = function(){
           var width = el.offsetWidth;
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give the img an ID and do the following :-

```
var heavyImage = document.getElementById("my-img");//assuming your img ID is my-img
heavyImage.onload = function(){
    //your code after image is fully loaded
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I updated the question, the image element comes from Javascript event, and is not part of the DOM document.

Comment: How it will be coming from JS event? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I added a new answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but if you add the image to the DOM, set an `onload`/`load` event-handler and *then* assign the `src` of the image, the event-handling should fire (once it's loaded) and allow you to find the width.

This is imperfect, though, since if the image is loaded from the browser's cache the `onload`/`load` event may not fire at all (particularly in Chromium/Chrome, I believe, though this is from memory of a bug that may, or may not, have since been fixed).

Comment: The 2nd paragraph should be heeded: onload is particularly icky. I think I've seen a jQuery plugin designed to try and make it behave better.

Answer (score 1):

For the chrome bug you can use the following:-

```
var BLANK = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==';//create a blank source

var tImg = document.getElementById("my-img");//get the image
var origSrc = tImg.src;//get the original src
tImg.src = BLANK;//change the img src to blank.
tImg.src = origSrc;//Change it back to original src. This will lead the chrome to load the image again.
tImg.onload= function(){
    //your code after the image load
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library called [PreloadJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS) or you can try something like this:

```
//Somewhere in your document loading:
loadImage(yourImage, callbackOnComplete);

function loadImage(image, callbackOnComplete){

   var self = this;
   if(!image.complete)
      window.content.setTimeout(
         function() { self.loadImage(image, callbackOnComplete)}
      ,1000);
   else callbackOnComplete();
}
```

I did this when I worked with images base64 which delay on loading.