# Struts2 trigger a table to load on completion

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jfreechart

I have a class that take a bit longer to complete that computes a list of values I graph and throughout that class I generate a few key values that I throw in a table.

So my question is how I do make that table wait for the charting action to complete to load the table.

My graph generation

```
<!-- Graph -->
    <s:if test="currentUser.getElec_end1() != null">
        <div id="graphContent"> 
            <img src="<s:url action='generateElectricityChart' />" />   
        </div>
    </s:if>
```

But I want this to trigger after the above generation is complete

```
        <div id="dateTable">
            <table id="pricingTable">
                 <tr><th>Pricing Start</th><th>Term Start</th><th>Term End</th><th>Last Date</th><th>Price</th></tr>
                 <tr><td><s:property value="currentUser.getElec_pricing_start1()" /></td><td><s:property value="currentUser.getElec_start1()" /></td><td><s:property value="currentUser.getElec_end1()" /></td><td><s:property value="currentUser.getElec_date1()" /></td><td><s:property value="getPrice1()" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I feel like the tricky part that is throwing me for a loop is that the above data in this table is not inherently tied to this action as they are initialized in my controller class that handles the page loading, page specific variables, sessions info, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, You are simply taking it wronG!

1. Images are loaded by browser, so you're just developing a URL on which the browser sends a get request to receive an image as a response. This request has nothing to do with the original request which already displayed the table.
2. Instead you could have a possible solution like :

   > Action 1 -> LoadJSP without table -> Load image using Javascript -> After
   >   image load make an ajax request to action 2 which returns the table ->
   >   push that table in the html DOM.

This [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/jquery-event-for-images-loaded) explains wisely on how to fire an event on image load using javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the response and link to explanation. I've actually been working on a solution like that for the last few hours!