# Jquery window load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is working great, however, I need to to be triggered once the page, including all images, is fully loaded.  I have read up on the difference between document and window, but have not been able to get it to work correctly. Here is the code I am currently working with.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
$('.field-name-field-animated-text').fadeIn(5000,function(){
$(this).animate({"top" : "300px"}, 4000);
 });    
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/ ?

Comment: And you are sure that the 'field-name' in your selector isn't supposed to be dynamic?

Comment: This is not a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/ since that question (as asked) is specific to knowing when all images have loaded, not just images. You've also linked to a question with no approved answer which seems less helpful.

Comment: @whoughton, I'm not sure I understand your point. First line of the other question: "Is it possible to detect when all images are loaded via a jQuery event?" First line of this question: "I have a function that is working great, however, I need to to be triggered once the page, including all images, is fully loaded." Both ask specifically about all images being loaded. (I also don't understand your statement: "...that question (as asked) is specific to knowing when all images have loaded, not just images.") The fact that the other question is unanswered doesn't seem relevant to duplication.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //EVERYTHING has loaded
    //do some stuff here
});
```

According to the docs "The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.”

There are some caveats though so read the spec: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: As specified in the jQuery documentation (https://api.jquery.com/load-event/), "There are several known caveats with this... It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser..." and several other problems.