# Confirmation for load multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery

Multiple image files being loaded into `#elem`.

How do I get confirmation when all images completes loading? Below is what I tried but that dosen't work correctly. How do I get a confirmation after the image are loaded?

```
for(vari=1;i<10;i++){
    if( $('#elem'+i+' .soldIcon' )  ) {
         //do other stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery event for images loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/jquery-event-for-images-loaded)

Comment: @A1rPun Thanks. That dosen't confirm all images are loaded?

Comment: Your code just confirm the tag is present not loaded.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Thanks. That makes scenes. HOw do I get confirmation when all 10 images are loaded?

Comment: Take a look to the referenced answer in @A1rPun comment.

Answer (score -2):

You can use window load completed method. it will be called when all the DOM elements are loaded

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: There are some caveats about this event on images => http://api.jquery.com/load-event/