# Detecting when HTML image source update is done

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to update an image source

```
$("#myImage").attr("src", imagePath);
```

Immediately after, I try to detect the image's width with

```
$("#myImage").width();
```

Looks like sometimes (especially on first update) the update is not done, and I get invalid data.

Is there a way to make sure the image finished loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.load();` will fire on the image when it's finished loading:

```
$("img.myImage").load(function(){
  alert("My width is " + $(this).width());
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Indeed it will. Sadly I tested it before answering... :) Beat me to it. +1

Comment: ...me too :( - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-something is a similar case.

Answer (score 0):

The image has a `onload` event like the document's body.

Make sure you set that event *before* you change the src.