# How to only fade content once it is ready in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ready

I've seen examples for `load()` and `ready()`, but they always seem to apply to the window or document body, or a div or img or something like that.

I have a `hover()` function, and when you hover over it, it uses `fadeIn()` to reveal it. Problem is, the images inside the div aren't loaded yet, so it ends up just appearing anyway. I need code that will only allow the image to fade when it's contents are fully loaded. When I just plug in other selectors like the following, it doesn't work

```
$(this).next(".menuPopup").ready(function () { //or load(), neither work
  fadeTo(300, 1);
});
```

**EDIT:** Relevant code

```
     $( '.leftMenuProductButton' ).hover (
            function () {

                                $(this).next(".menuPopup").stop().css("opacity", 1).fadeIn('slow');


            },
            function () {



                $(this).next(".menuPopup").stop().hide();


    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="leftMenuProductButton"> Product 1</div>
                                <div id="raceramps56" class="menuPopup"><IMG SRC="myimage.jpeg"> </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML so that we can give an accurate answer?

Comment: I still don't see any images 'inside the div' that you are referring to. Are you talking about CSS background images?

Comment: Sorry - edited correctly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably go with chaining the animations:

```
$(this).next(".menuPopup").fadeIn(300, function() {
    $(this).children('.inside_image').css(
        'opacity':'0',
        'display':'show'
    );
    $(this).children('.inside_image').animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 300);
});
```

I've done something like this before, and it worked pretty well. I think a lot of Lightboxes do this.

Comment: Make sure you update the status of the question if an answer works out for you :)

Comment: I was hoping someone would offer a solution oriented around load() or ready()

Comment: There's a time and place for every function. In my experience, this isn't the kind of script that best utilizes the load() or ready() functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
$(window).load()
```

is probably what you're looking for.

See: [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-something)

Comment: Yes, but I have multiple popups that this occurs with. window load() doesn't work after the initial page has loaded, and changes are being made.

Answer (score 0):

You could use window.onLoad, that doesn't fire until everything is loaded.