# How can i know if all <img> loaded in div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i know if all  loaded in div using jQuery

i want to do this after load all img in #slider div

```
var imgHeight = $("#slider img").height();
alert(imgHeight);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Official way to ask jQuery wait for all images to load before executing something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-something)

Comment: $(window).load this can help me if i want to know when all images in page loaded :) but i want not that.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `load` event

```
$('#slider img').load(function(){
    var imgHeight = $(this).height();
    alert(imgHeight);
});
```

if there are more than one image, and you only want to obtain the height after they have *all* loaded, try this code

```
var img = $('#slider img');
var length = img.length;

img.load(function(){
    length--;

    if(length === 0){
        alert("All images loaded");
    };
});
```

---

Well, I've tested the code, and it appears that the problem hasn't got anything to do with the code. When loading the page with the images already in the cache, this is what I get:

[image]

Strangely, this does not occur when I force the browser not to use the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Attach an `onload` event listener to each image in the slider.
- In the listener:

  - Give the current image a custom attribute to mark it is 'ready'.
  - Check if all images are ready. If so, do your thing (i.e. `alert(imageHeight)`)

untested:

```
(function(){
  var slider=document.getElementById('slider'),
      images=slider.getElementsByTagName('img'), image, i=-1;

  while (image=images[i]) {
    image.onload=function(){
      this['data-ready']=true;
      var image, i=-1;
      while (image=images[i]) if (!image['data-ready']) return;
      // all images are ready; do your thing here
      // ...
    }
  }
}());
```