# How can I equalize the heights of divs in table based on the tallest div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am creating a page that has a table with a bunch of images in it. Each image is wrapped in a set of divs. The images are user-added, so I have no control over the aspect ratio, but I will be enforcing a maximum width and height on uploaded images.

```
<table class="pl_upload"> 
  <tr class="row1"> 
    <td class="col1"> 
      <div>
        <div class="img-container">
          <a href="#"><img src="img.jpg" width="182"  alt="X" /></a>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </td>
    .......
```

What I would like to do is calculate the height of the tallest image div in the table, and then make the all of the image divs that same height using jQuery.

I made a jsfiddle page for it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Evolution/27EJB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var max = 0;

$(".pl_upload img").each(function() {
 if($(this).height() > max) {
  max = $(this).height();
 }
});

$(".img-container").height(max);
```

Comment: You need to wait for the images to load or it will not prevail!

Comment: Thanks Stef! Beautiful example. I border those divs and everything now lines up perfectly.

Comment: Great - glad it worked. Robert's example below might actually be better in practice because this event fires before images are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for, however this should be able to get the tallest image on the page and then set the `div`'s on the page to that height.

Also, per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-something) if you wrap the function in `$(window).load()` it should only be called once all images are loaded.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var tallest = 0;
    $("img").each(function() {
        var h = $(this).height();
        if (h > tallest) {
            tallest = h;
        }
    });
    $("div").css("height", tallest);
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/27EJB/8/).

If this is not what you need please elaborate your question a bit.

Comment: Brilliant Mark. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for your time. Love jsfiddle!

Comment: No problem glad I could help, I love me some jsfiddle as well!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be what your looking for:

```
var Max = 0;
var Images = $(".img-container img");

Images.each(function(k,v){
    $(this).load(function(){
        if(Max < $(this).height())
        {
            Max = $(this).height();
        }

        if(k == Images.length)
        {
            $(".img.container").height(max);
        }
    });
})
```

Test Case: http://jsfiddle.net/27EJB/1/

Im not saying it works exactly how you want it but from your description this is what i come up with.