# wait for all image to load jquery ajax / jquery pjax

Tags: jquery, ajax, pjax

heres a snipset of what im trying to do

```
$.pjax = function( options ) {
  var $container = $(options.container),
      success = options.success || $.noop

  // We don't want to let anyone override our success handler.
  delete options.success

  // We can't persist $objects using the history API so we must use
  // a String selector. Bail if we got anything else.
  if ( typeof options.container !== 'string' )
    throw "pjax container must be a string selector!"

  var defaults = {
    timeout: 650,
    push: true,
    replace: false,
    // We want the browser to maintain two separate internal caches: one for
    // pjax'd partial page loads and one for normal page loads. Without
    // adding this secret parameter, some browsers will often confuse the two.
    data: { _pjax: true },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
      $container.trigger('start.pjax')
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PJAX', 'true')
    },
    error: function(){
      window.location = options.url
    },
    complete: function(){


$container.trigger('end.pjax')
},
success: function(data){
  // If we got no data or an entire web page, go directly
  // to the page and let normal error handling happen.
  if ( !$.trim(data) || /<html/i.test(data) )
    return window.location = options.url

  // Make it happen.
  // i think im not getting it right.
  $(window).load(
      function() {
          $container.html(data)
      }
  );
```

like [Official way to ask jQuery wait for all images to load before executing something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-something) but its after an jquery ajax request.

as you can see at the bottom `// Make it happen`, im trying to **return the html(data) after its all image from the html(data) is ready to serve**, can we do that somehow?

thanks!

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to insert the loaded HTML into the DOM before the browser will start loading any of the images. You should be able to insert it into a hidden (`display:none`) div, and set the `.load()` callback on that hidden div.

[This plugin](https://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js) improves the `.load()` event so that it is more consistently triggered on image loading.