# jQuery each() working weird

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am trying to get the width of some nested image. I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="slide" id="Slide1">
        <a href="#" title="Some Title" target="_blank">
             <img src="images/photo1.jpg" alt="Slide 1" class="slideImg">
        </a>
        <div class="caption" style="width: 476px">
            <h1>Stuff</h1>
            <p>Some Stuff Description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="slide" id="Slide2">
        <a href="#" title="Some Title" target="_blank">
             <img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="Slide 2" class="slideImg">
        </a>
        <div class="caption" style="width: 476px">
            <h1>Stuff</h1>
            <p>Some Stuff Description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And working with jQuery, I want to get the width of each IMG so then I can set (1024px - that width) to the correct "CAPTION DIV" ( `<div class="caption">` ). Both of this script, are giving me a second image whose width is "0", an impossible thing.

```
$('.slideImg').each(function(){
    alert($(this).width());             
 });
$('.slide').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    alert($(this).find('a').find('img').width());
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure both images were loaded. Because the second image could of course have a zero width, if it was not loaded from the server.

Comment: [Your code works fine in JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hBWC/). You must have something else that's not included in the markup.

Comment: ouch, I think I did not paste the Slider Code, sorry, I will edit that

Comment: It works fine here.. Maybe your Image was no loaded properly..http://jsfiddle.net/9wZ4P/1/

Comment: Sorry, I am having problems with my proxy, I was trying to edit the question but I could not, I am using SlideJs, wwww.slidejs.com, and all this function, is used inside: slidesLoaded: function() {, I have tried to take it out from there, but it is the same, i do not know what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked its working fine.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

      $('.slide').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
            alert($(this).find('a').find('img').width());
});

    });
```

Comment: Thsi is not working for me. I was trying to edit the question, because I have a Slide, that could be the hint.

Answer (score 0):

So did I and it works for me.

Which browser are you using?

I tested in Chrome 22, IE 9, Firefox 15

Answer (score 0):

May be you can also check if your image is hidden. because jquery has problems in computing dimensions for hidden elements

Comment: Yes, the first slide is only visible, that could be the problem, because first loop is giving me the correct data, but the others are wrong. How could I deal with this 'hidden' bug?

Comment: may be you can use "off-left technique" as described in the below link http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Tabs. just before calculating width apply the above technique and after the calculation remove the technique. so that it will not impact your layout

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the images haven't fully loaded when your jQuery is running.  See here: [Official way to ask jQuery wait for all images to load before executing something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin)

Also, `clientWidth` will give you the actual rendered width of the image

You might try:

```
$('.slide').load(function() {
  alert(this.clientWidth);
})
```