# callback when a static html <img> has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im aware of ways to see when an image created with javascript or jquery has loaded, such as

```
.loaded(callback(){

})
```

or imagesLoaded library,

but how do i know when image created with a plain  tag inside html document has loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this :

```
 <img src='my.jpg' id='myImage' />

    $("#myImage").on('load', function(){
      // image loaded .. do something
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).load()` waits for the DOM and all images to load, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545005/1970746).

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that the image may or may not be already loaded. I would just pre-load it as usual. If it's already loaded, the load event will still trigger.

```
$(function(){

    var src = $("#myimg")[0].src,
        img = new Image();

    $(img).load(function(){
        console.log('image loaded');
    })[0].src = src;

});
```