# After jquery .load() I cannot operate with script on images

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

After clicking on menu item data is loaded to "#content". I want to use function makeGray() that turns pictures with class "galleryList" to grayscale and saturating them after pointing with mouse. Unfortunately, code below doesn't work until second click:

```
$(document).delegate(element, 'click', function() {
    $('#content')               
    .stop()
    .animate({opacity: 0}, 'fast', function() {
        $(this).load('subpage.html', function() {
            makeGray('.galleryList');
        })
        .animate({opacity: 1});
    });
});
```

**Edit after Kevin and Daniel posts:**
[There](http://pavlucco.herobo.com/scripts/grayscale.js) is code of script making pictures gray. The problem is how to wait until images are fully loaded and then run script.

Comment: the callback happens when the request is complete, it doesn't wait for images returned by the request to finish loading. you'll need to preload the images.

Comment: html is loaded, images inside html are not yet (may take more time). don't know how is it important for your code to wait for images to be loaded.  

**edit:** Kevin was 1st :)

Comment: How make it wait until images are fully loaded?

Comment: @pavlucco there is no built-in way to do that, you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: see [Check if an image is loaded (no errors) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript)

Comment: this answer talks about a plugin that seems to do exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5163865/810899