# Execute jQuery function after image is downloaded or after some delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delay this part of jquery code by 2 seconds

```
//set equal height of two div's
//$(".pg-right-bar").css({ "height": $("#pg-left-bar").height() })
var leftbar = $(".pg-left-bar").height();
var rightbar = $(".pg-right-bar").height()-4; // remove 4 pxels from righ div
leftbar = leftbar - 20;

if (leftbar > rightbar) 
{
    $(".pg-right-bar").css({ "height": $("#pg-left-bar").height() - 10 })
}
else 
{
    $(".pg-left-bar").css({ "height": $("#pg-right-bar").height() })
    $(".pg-right-bar").css({ "height": rightbar+"px" })
}
```

Actually my page has two divs `pg-left-bar div` & `pg-right-bar div` my left bar div has page contents and right bar div has image. and i have to assign both divs same height depending on which one has greater height.

So i use above logic for this but problem with this code is that it executes before right-bar image is downloaded which results in is that most of the time first condition is true. Is there a way i can delay the execution of this code till image in `pg-right-bar` is downloaded.

or how can i wrap this code in a function with 3 seconds delay.

After trouble shooting i came to conclusion that code logic is fine it is the image which take time to download & in between jquery is executed and assign wrong dimensions to both the div

Complete...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    App.init();
    App.initNavMenu();
    //Tabs
    App.InitCustomTabs();
    App.initMarqueeBrands();
    //activatte tooltip
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
});
```

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem by wrapping the code in following function.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var leftbar = $(".pg-left-bar").height();
    var rightbar = $(".pg-right-bar").height()-4; // remove 4 pxels from righ div
    leftbar = leftbar - 20;
    if (leftbar > rightbar) 
    {
        $(".pg-right-bar").css({ "height": $("#pg-left-bar").height() - 10 })
    }
    else 
    {
        $(".pg-left-bar").css({ "height": $("#pg-right-bar").height() })
        $(".pg-right-bar").css({ "height": rightbar+"px" })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple code after image is loaded.

```
var img = $(something_to_find_image)
img.ready(function_to_call_after_load_of_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do:

- `$(document).ready()` is triggered right after the DOM is loaded (images might still be in progress of being loaded)
- `$(window).load()` is triggered after everything (including the images) have been loaded.

I am assuming you want to wait until everything is loaded, so you can use `$(window).load()`. However, if you want to show a spinning wheel, hourglass etc until all images are loaded, display it inside `$(document).ready()` and hide it inside `$(window).load()`.

Comment: Actually i did use window.load first for some reason it didnt work. But after further troubleshooting i managed to make it work.. my answer is also pointing to similar reason as mentioned by you. Thanks anyway. Just forgot for a moment basic difference between two.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem by wrapping the code in following function.

```
$(window).load(function() {
            var leftbar = $(".pg-left-bar").height();
    var rightbar = $(".pg-right-bar").height()-4; // remove 4 pxels from righ div
    leftbar = leftbar - 20;

    if (leftbar > rightbar) {
        $(".pg-right-bar").css({ "height": $("#pg-left-bar").height() - 10 })
    }
    else {
        $(".pg-left-bar").css({ "height": $("#pg-right-bar").height() })
        $(".pg-right-bar").css({ "height": rightbar+"px" })
    }
});
```

Scenario well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the code after the images have loaded, setting a 2 second delay is sloppy. It could run too early, or way too late. Using fixed delays to execute code after a event of which the duration isn't fixed should be avoided, instead use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //code goes here
});
```

or

```
$(window).load(function () {
  //code goes here
});
```

$(document).ready will only be called after the DOM is ready
and
$(window).load() after everything else is ready (best suits your needs)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides the
[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event method that can be used to invoke a function once the window is completely
loaded.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  //your code here
  alert("All the assets of the page have been loaded");

});
```