# jquery works in console, but not in linked js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery script to add a class (portrait or landscape) depending on their dimensions. Then I am using jQuery to center the image vertically. The script works perfectly when I past it into the console, but not when I link it in the document head. Here is the code I have:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(
    function() {
        jQuery(".imgResize").each( function () {
            var $this = jQuery(this);
            if ( $this.width() > $this.height() ) {
                $this.addClass("landscape");
            } else if ( $this.width() < $this.height() ) {
                $this.addClass("portrait");
            } else {
        }
        var $h = $this.height();
        $this.css('margin-top', + $h / -2 + "px");
    });
});
```

What would cause this issue?

Comment: If you are writing `Console.log` and try to run into `IE` then it will not work. `IE` not support `Console`

Comment: are there images in the `imgResize` element

Comment: @AmitAgrawal I'm using Chrome's js Console

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, I have 12 images with the class .imgResize

Comment: Where is `console.log` bro ?

Comment: that is the problem... when you run the script the images may not be loaded

Comment: @SnakeEyes I'm not using console.log, bro. I'm just pasting the code into Chrome's console from devtools

Comment: There might be a problem that your Script is running before the loading of image or dom. That's why it is happening.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Why would the images not be loaded? I'm using .ready on the document

Comment: "Doesn't work" is too vague. What does happen? Are any errors reported in the JS console? Does the function run at all (add a breakpoint or console.log to test)?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin

Comment: can you put the html along with this code in some snippet like gist and share it with us, it'll be easier to help you then, Otherwise we all will keep guessing

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thank you for your answer! It worked for me. I noticed your answer was deleted. If you repost it I will mark it correct and upvote. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the images to be loaded

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".imgResize").on('load', function () {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if ($this.width() > $this.height()) {
            $this.addClass("landscape");
        } else if ($this.width() < $this.height()) {
            $this.addClass("portrait");
        } else {

        }
        var $h = $this.height();
        $this.css('margin-top', +$h / -2 + "px");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually In your **case**, your jQuery Script is running before loading of the image. So, if you want to run your script on after loading the image.

Then you need to use [jQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

**Solution**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(
    function() {
        jQuery(".imgResize").on('load', function () {
            var $this = jQuery(this);
            if ( $this.width() > $this.height() ) {
                $this.addClass("landscape");
            } else if ( $this.width() < $this.height() ) {
                $this.addClass("portrait");
            } else {
        }
        var $h = $this.height();
        $this.css('margin-top', + $h / -2 + "px");
    });
});
```