# Execute function after element has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to execute a function after an element has been loaded.

jQuery's `load()` event seems to make this easy, but it was deprecated in v1.8. I'm looking for a modern version of a similar thing to this:

```
$( "img.userIcon" ).load(function() {
  if ( $( this ).height() > 100) {
    $( this ).addClass( "bigImg" );
  }
});
```

Must be cross-browser, can be jQuery or vanilla JS.

Comment: @kmoe Wrong `.load` I guess...

Comment: @VisioN oops... well, now I wish I could undo flags

Comment: The .load function wasn't cross browswer supported, so that's why it's deprecated, I don't think it's been replaced.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/  The doc says to use the `load` event and gives this example : `$( "#book" ).load(function() { ... }`

Comment: @TCHdvlp It also says that it's deprecated and that using it for this exact purpose is not cross browser supported...

Comment: ho ! My bad, it's written so tiny

Comment: @TCHdvlp No worries, read the caveats section of the page you linked.

Comment: @sage88 Where is that written?

Comment: @VisioN http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ see this section: Caveats of the load event when used with images

Comment: @sage88 Where is it written that these caveats were the main reason for deprecating the method? Please see the [following ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733) in the tracker for the official reason.

Comment: @VisioN You're right for the reason it was deprecated. That said, it and all alternative forms of it, have never worked well for the purpose the author has, and so should not be used.

Comment: So what should I use? The suggestion in the 'duplicate' question doesn't seem to work in my tests.

Comment: @sanjaypooyzer Unfortunately, I don't think there is a cross broswer way to do this. I think the answer below is probably your best bet, but it's not going to work reliably or consistently see the comments on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin which is what your question is actually a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) says that `.load(callback)` is shorthand for `.on('load', callback)`

The `.load(callback)` was deprecated because of ambiguity with the AJAX `.load(callback)` (see [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733))

Comment: This is not the AJAX load method, it is the load event which was deprecated in jQuery 1.8

Comment: @JayBlanchard This answer is about `load` event and is correct in terms of the way of thinking. The method was deprecated because of ambiguity.

Comment: This isn't cross browser supported.

Comment: @sage88 This was not the main reason for deprecation.