# imagesloaded javascript library: what is the browser & device support?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, browser-support, imagesloaded, cross-device

**imagesLoaded** seems like the best solution (at the time of writing, Nov 2014) to [detect whether an image is loaded or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript).

I found that imagesLoaded library has the following characteristics:

- license: MIT License
- dependencies: none
- weight (minified & gzipped) : 7kb minified (light!)
- download builder (helps to cut weight) : no need, already tiny
- on Github : YES
- community & contributors : pretty big, 4000+ members, although only 13 contributors
- history & contributions : stable as relatively old (since 2010) but still active project

All the above features point into the direction of a very high quality product. However, there is a couple of information I still cannot find explicitly mentioned nor on the official website [imagesloaded.desandro.com](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/), nor on the Github page [github.com/desandro/imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded):

1. what is the browser support?
2. what is the device support?

Even though I assume the answer to the 2nd question being obvious, I would appreciate a confirmation.

**EDIT**: I just remembered this answer mentioned it working on IE7+ https://stackoverflow.com/a/19959809/759452, further feedback is still welcome though

**EDIT 2**: I just found another source saying it does not support IE7, this time by the creator of the library himself, see message from "desandro on 30 Nov 2012" on [github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/16](http://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/16)

Comment: It works on IE7+, what else do you need to know ?

Comment: I just found another source saying it does not support IE7, this time by the creator of the library himself, see message from "desandro on 30 Nov 2012" on https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/16

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But I am looking for a solid proof or statement from a trusted contributor. That's why I took the time to actually write a proper question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Well, I used imagesLoaded on many IE8+ projects, without any trouble. Anyway, I think when Desandro says IE7 is no longer supported, you can deduct IE8 is. And about smartphones, tablets, etc : most of the browsers on those devices are based on webkit, so it surely will work. Windows Phone still use IE (Trident), but in a decent version (like IE10 I think).

Comment: My post that you mention referring to IE7+ support may have been for an older version of the library. It certainly worked back when I tested it. I've removed it from my answer anyway, because if the author himself doesn't say it's supported, it could break with any update.

Comment: Thanks for that. It definitely helps to have your answer up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that **imagesloaded** is officially supported by IE8+.

See the answer from David DeSandro (the creator of the library) on https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/168

> Officially, imagesLoaded v3 does not support IE7 and below.

And also:

> In my testing, it was successful in IE8, IE9, IE10, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox on desktop, and Mobile Safari for iOS.

Note: I will do some further testing & update this answer accordingly