# jQuery each is too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, each

I'm trying to add attribute `data-size` to my parent `div`.

Here is my code:

```
var width, height;
$(".galerie img").each(function() {
  width = this.naturalWidth;
  height = this.naturalHeight;
  $(this).parent().attr('data-size', width+'x'+height);
});
```

I have around 40 pictures on 1 page. On this way, not every of my div get 'data-size'. Sometimes only 1/2 of them, sometimes 1/3 of them or only 5 of them. How can I fix it?

Comment: are you using this in document.ready, means are you waiting till DOM gets ready

Comment: @Farhan I have it in $(function() { ... });

Comment: If you think `$.each` is fast you should see a `for` loop

Comment: @SterlingArcher How can I select all of my ".galerie img" with for?

Comment: Without seeing an example of your HTML, it's hard to say what the problem is. I think you're assuming that `each` is "too fast", it could well be that there is another problem.

Comment: try to use $(function(){} in $(window).on("load", function() {}); this is because i think not every images are fully loaded before each() run. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin

Comment: @Farhan - See second comment - he already is...

Comment: my mistake @LeeTaylor, correct me if i am wrong. $(function(){...}) is equal to document.ready not window.ready

Comment: @Farhan - thx you, its working now

Comment: Are the images already in the html on load, or are they fetched with another script asynchronously?

Comment: You might want to also consider using image lazy loading: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use document.ready in window.load. this is because not every images are loaded properly before each function fires

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
var width, height;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".galerie img").each(function() {
          width = this.naturalWidth;
          height = this.naturalHeight;
          $(this).parent().attr('data-size', width+'x'+height);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: window onload cannot guarantee all images are loaded

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I have seen your answer and it looks pretty good to me. I have used my answer's code in one of my project and it does good there too. but your answer is more logical.

Comment: for more reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin

Answer (score 1):

Use a `new Image()` and wait for it's `onload`

```
var width,
    height;
$(".galerie img").each(function() {
  var $that = $(this);
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
     width = this.naturalWidth;
     height = this.naturalHeight;
     $that.parent().attr('data-size', width+'x'+height);
  });
  img.src = this.src;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are triggering the each when the images are not loaded. Maybe you should check if the last one is loaded before doing it

try to check it with something like this:

```
 if (typeof img.naturalWidth !== "undefined" && img.naturalWidth === 0) {
```

or the [imagesLoaded javascript library.](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/)