# Run JS code when all HTML has loaded (not images)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute a js code which adds a class to all elements that have specific class eg. `.lookbook-block` however, I think I'd have to wait until all the HTML has loaded before this loop is executed, but the page had a lot of images so I don't want to use window.load ad that will wait until all images have loaded, which will delay the execution. Is there a way I can wait until only the HTML has loaded?

Thanks!

Comment: window.onload = function(){} ? jQuery $(document).ready(function(){}); ? or place the script tag at the bottom of your html body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Official way to ask jQuery wait for all images to load before executing something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin), answer talks about document ready vs window onload

Comment: @rorypicko actually load will not do the trick here, i was suspicious about this event and in closer look - > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload it is far from efficient in this case

Comment: You may also want to look at lazy-loading your images in one way or another, so you can mess with the DOM as soon as jQuery's _$(document).ready_ has kicked in, while images are still loading in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Put script at the bottom of the html

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
// Your code here.
});
```

This adds a callback function to execute when the `ready` event is triggered from the jQuery library. You can read more about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). You can do the same thing by using this, which is more clear:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Your code
});
```

Comment: A little explanation would make for a more informative answer.

Comment: I added some more explanation.

Comment: What is the vanilla JS equivalent of this?