# Wait for image to load plugin not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, waitforimages

I'm using the plugin from https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages to detect when is the image loaded.

Below is my code:

```js
$('.marquee').waitForImages(function() {
  console.log('All images have loaded.');
  setTimeout(startMarquee);
}, function(loaded, count, success) {
  console.log(loaded + ' of ' + count + 
   ' images has ' + (success ? 'loaded' : 'failed to load') + '.');
  $(this).addClass('loaded');
});
```

I will start a marquee scrolling of images when the images is loaded complete.

My problem is, some images had not yet load but just show a small empty square box like this:
 [image],

the plugin also consider it already load. Any idea how to fix it?

Does showing a small empty square box only is consider image loaded?

Comment: broken plugin - report to plugin author would be nice for the author

Comment: I have uploaded the empty box image

Comment: Thanks. Nobody here knows what one of them looks like

Comment: @JaromandaX here are some more if you need: https://www.google.nl/search?q=broken+image+icon ;)

Comment: The image you show is what is shown onerror. The plugin likely consider that `done` too or it would never finish

Comment: so, now it's just a matter of creating a pattern matching algorithm against all known possible broken image images, and try to predict future ones, and step 3 = profit

Comment: U mean that is consider loaded also? But I want the real image to come out. Anyway to wait for the image to come out?

Comment: frivolity aside - how are you loading the images whose class is .marquee - perhaps the problem is that you are not doing that part right

Comment: It is broken because it was not loaded and never will unless you reload perhaps

Comment: I have a div with class marquee to put my scrolling image :<div class="marquee"></div>. Is it cannot do like this?

Comment: How do I add in a reload function if I face a broken image?

Comment: You could use the each callback to determine if an image failed and perform some other action - the plugin author.

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Just write your own.

```
<marquee id="marquee" style="visiblity:hidden">
  <img src="image1.jpg" onload="countMe(this,1)" onerror="countMe(this,0)"/>
  <img src="image1.jpg" onload="countMe(this,1)" onerror="countMe(this,0)"/>
  <img src="image1.jpg" onload="countMe(this,1)" onerror="countMe(this,0)"/>
 </marquee>

 <script>
 var imageCount = 0, nofImages=$("#marquee img"); 
 function countMe(img,success) {
   if (!success) $(img).hide();
   imageCount++;
   if (imageCount == nofImages) $("#marquee").show();
 }
 </script>
```

If you want to give the image a chance and not load the marquee if permanent error you can try

```
<marquee id="marquee" style="visiblity:hidden">
  <img src="image1.jpg" onload="countMe(this)" onerror="reloadMe(this)"/>
  <img src="image2.jpg" onload="countMe(this)" onerror="reloadMe(this)"/>
  <img src="image3.jpg" onload="countMe(this)" onerror="reloadMe(this)"/>
 </marquee>

 <script>
 var imageCount = 0, nofImages=$("#marquee img"); 
 function countMe(img) {
   imageCount++;
   if (imageCount == nofImages) $("#marquee").show();
 }
 function reloadMe(img) {
   var tries = img.getAttribute("tries")?parseInt(img.getAttribute("tries"),10):1;
   if (tries) == 3) return; // stop it
   tries++;
   img.setAttribute("tries",tries);
   img.src=img.src;
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Your function will hide the broken image. How bout if I really want the image? Do I reload the page?

Comment: You will likely not get the image if it errors. If the image exists you need to fix why it gives error

Comment: Can't I do something like this: <img src="image1.jpg" onload="countMe(this,1)" onerror='window.location.reload();'/>

Comment: That would be very unwise. Then if an image did not exist, it would reload non-stop

Comment: I am getting the image from a server. This happen only when the server is just startup. And I got 5 client which will get the image from the server. Is there a possibility that the server can't cope with so many client in one go that's why the image can't get trough?

Comment: Yes that is possible. You can use setTimeout to defer loading. To reload broken images 3 times, see my update

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait till all page images loaded before running your marquee code you can use:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    // all page html and images loaded
});
```

More details can be found in this questions:
[Official way to ask jQuery wait for all images to load before executing something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin)