# Forcing jQuery to run after page finished loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a small jQuery script that resizes elements according to their background image's aspect ratio. In certain instances, it doesn't work in time, and I believe this is because the code runs before the images finish downloading.

Basically, I have `<div>` elements that will have a certain sized background image, and I want the element to be the exact same size. If there is a better way than with JS, I'm all ears.

I can manually set a delay, but is there a way to ONLY run the code after the images finish downloading?

I currently have it in `$(document).ready(function(){...});` inside my footer.

Comment: Maybe this might help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin

Comment: Another link which might be useful https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/run-javascript-only-after-entire-page-has-loaded/.

Answer (score 7):

Please try

```
    $(window).on("load", function() {
       // your logic here.
    });
```

Instead of

```
    $(document).ready(function(){...});
```

Note - load is called when all assets are done loading, including images. ready is fired when the DOM is ready for interaction.