# .clientWidth/.width in JavaScript is not working on img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a JavaScript slider for that I need to get the width of the images so I can apply `translateX` on them but when I try to get the width of first image of the div it returns 0.

I'm pretty sure that the error is in the `var size = carouselImg[0].clientWidth;` line but I don't know how to fix it. I placed the JavaScript code below the HTML.

```js
var carouselSlide = document.querySelector(".carousel-slide");
var carouselImg = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-slide img");

let count = 1;

var size = carouselImg[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * count) + 'px)';

console.log(size);
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel-container{
 width: 900px;
 border: 3px solid black;
 margin: auto;
}

.carousel-slide{
 display: flex;
 height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
 <div class="carousel-slide">
  
  <img src="img4.png" id="lastImg" alt="">
  <img src="img1.png" alt="">
  <img src="img2.png" alt="">
  <img src="img3.png" alt="">
  <img src="img4.png" alt="">
  <img src="img1.png" id="firstImg" alt="">

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you waiting for the images to finish loading before attempting to fetch their widths? If you fetch the width without waiting, the width will be `0` because the image hasn't loaded yet. Note that a `$(document).ready( ... )` will **not** wait for the images to load, however a `$(window).load( ... )` *will*. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser does not have time to load the image. The `clientWidth` will be 0 until the image either loads or is shown as a broken image. Also, setting `alt=""` will always make a broken image's `clientWidth` be 0 even after the browser decides that the image is broken. (In the question's snippet, the images' `alt` attributes are set this way.) This was all tested in Chrome 76.

The snippet below should work (tested in Chrome 76). I put your script in `window.onload` and gave the images `alt` attributes.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var carouselSlide = document.querySelector(".carousel-slide");
  var carouselImg = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-slide img");

  let count = 1;

  var size = carouselImg[0].clientWidth;

  carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * count) + 'px)';

  console.log(size);
}
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel-container{
 width: 900px;
 border: 3px solid black;
 margin: auto;
}

.carousel-slide{
 display: flex;
 height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
 <div class="carousel-slide">
  
  <img src="img4.png" id="lastImg" alt="1">
  <img src="img1.png" alt="2">
  <img src="img2.png" alt="3">
  <img src="img3.png" alt="4">
  <img src="img4.png" alt="5">
  <img src="img1.png" id="firstImg" alt="6">

 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same problem I solved it by changing the place of the Javascript file link in my HTML file I first load the CSS and then Javascript like

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Slideshow</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="main.js" defer charset="utf-8"></script>
```