# jQuery(document).ready() load() aspx

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.3.1 and saying `$('#somediv').load('somepage.aspx')` An aspx that have a Repeater which loads few images. When loading is complete a `cycle()` function (jQuery plug-in) will be called upon them.

Now I have this working on http://www.techlipse.net/test/agb via the function called from the menu-event-handlers (a combo box). When it is loaded via the event handler of the combobox I call `cycle()` plugin as a callback function to the `load()` method, or function .. I think I might have misunderstood some of the fundemantals of javascript, or why the `document.ready()` is firing long before the images are fully loaded therefore failing the `cycle()` plug in. When it is said to be a bug of jQuery1.3.1 that it does wait for them to load. Posted here:

[JQuery is waiting for images to load before executing document.ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477463/jquery-is-waiting-for-images-to-load-before-executing-document-ready/1156171#1156171)

any help .?

Answer (score 2):

document.ready fires once the document is ready. Not the images. You'll have to run a second check on images to check they have totally loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `$(document).ready` is that it fires as soon as the DOM is manipulable, but before `window.onload` - which fires after all HTTP traffic is done with.

Comment: Thanks.. so other than images, are there anything else that are not included to the DOM structure?

Comment: external CSS may not have loaded either.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade from 1.3.1 ASAP.  Its $(document).ready() functionality was buggy, making generally correct answers about $(document).ready() not necessarily accurate in your situation.